# How to style encapsulated child components in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to style encapsulated child components in angular?

Following are the child and parent components with view encapsulation enabled.

```
** child

//template
<div class="child-container"> </div>

// class
@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

```
** parent

//template
<div class="parent-container"> </div>

// class
@Component({
  selector: "app-parent",
  templateUrl: "./parent.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./parent.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

How can I select a particular class inside the **Child** component from the parent component's stylesheet and change it's style?

```
** parent

//template
<div class="parent-container">
<app-child></app-child>
 </div>

// class
@Component({
  selector: "app-parent",
  templateUrl: "./parent.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./parent.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})

//styles
app-child {
.child-container {
background colour: red;
}
}
```

**Currently when I try to select a class from the child component, I'm not being able to override it's styles. Please help!**

Remember that **ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom** is required for my used cased. So we have to keep that in mind.

Comment: Currently when I try to select a class from the child component, I'm not being able to override it's styles. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

css variables are accessible through the shadow dom..
so in your app-parent component scss, you should be able to do something like

```
--child-comp-background: red;
```

and in your app child component scss,

```
background-color: var(--child-comp-background, white) //white is a default incase the variable isnt defined or passed down from the parent
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :host-context() to do that

```
:host-context(.parent-container) .child-container{
...style here
}
```

Here the demo: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/shadow-dom-root-context?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.css)